# PHP preg_match: How is this variable(67278) to preg_match working?

Tags: php

Ex: 67278

How can I do this using preg_match???

How can I get this information with preg_match?

```
 $data = '<script>fcGetPlayerInsights("67278")</script>)';

 preg_match("/tr\('(.*?)'/",$data,$match);
 print_r($match);
```

Comment: What relation do the `tr` prefix and `'` single quote in your pattern have to the actual source?

Comment: What if you make it more simple and do an explode on the   "   value ?

Comment: Please show the full (or at least more) page text so that we can see that you are working with valid html.  Surely looking for 5 digits is not a robust solution.  Is this your whole input string?

Answer (score 2):

I do not recommend regex on html unless it's the only way...

But:

```
if(preg_match("/(\d{5})/", $data)){
     echo "a five digit number is there";
}else{
     echo "there is no five digit number";
}
```

May work..
However I recommend you to at least use `strip_tags` on the $data.

```
if(preg_match("/(\d{5})/", strip_tags($data))){
     echo "a five digit number is there";
}else{
     echo "there is no five digit number";
}
```

That removes the html from the string and leaves you with only `fcGetPlayerInsights("67278"))`to regex on, which is a bit safer.

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/hNO

Answer (score 0):

With [T-Regx](https://t-regx.com) you can go:

```
$data = '<script>fcGetPlayerInsights("67278")</script>)';

$result = pattern('fcGetPlayerInsights\("\d+"\)')->match($data)->all();
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use an html document parser to isolate the script tags for stability, then apply your regex pattern on the full inner html of any qualifying tags and if you are only expecting one match, you can break after finding the desired substring.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9lGbb))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<script>fcGetPlayerInsights("67278")</script>
<p>TEST</p><ul><li>1</li><li>fcGetPlayerInsights("24569")</li><li>3</li></ul>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('script') as $script) {
    if (preg_match('~^fcGetPlayerInsights\("(\d+)"\)$~', $script->nodeValue, $match)) {
        echo $match[1];
        break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
67278
```

Comment: I would LOVE to see a comment with the DV.  There has been a marked spike in no-comment-DVs on my answers in the last couple months.  Why damage Stack Overflow by lowering the page position of stable answers?